# Libgdx Box2D body rotation around point sprite position

Tags: libgdx, rotation, sprite, box2d

I need that my body rotate around specific point like shown in picture.
[image]
I already done that by this line of code (Please  let me know if there is a better way)

```
PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(1.8f / PPM, 0.2f / PPM, new Vector2(2,2), 0); // vector2 is
```

now I want to position sprite accordingly to my rotating body. Here what I did

```
sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x * 32 - sprite.getWidth() / 2, body.getPosition().y * 32 - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
```

and here how I draw everything

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch sb){
        System.out.println(body.getWorldCenter());
        sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
        sprite.draw(sb);
    }
```

Strange things happen when I run my code. I seee that body rotating correctly, but sprite rotates around its origin (middle of a sprite) because of this line `sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);` however I need that sprite position would be always the same as my body position. How can I cheve this?

Comment: Check whether this helps: http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/12/quick-fix-rotation-problem-of-box2d-objects-created-from-tiled-map-editor-in-libgdx-solved/

Answer (score 0):

The origin of all box2d bodies is their location.

**Important: The box2d bodies of type box/circle get centered around their location, while the other types of bodies are NOT.**

If you want to sync your rotation with the sprite, you should position the sprite origin over the body location and then rotate.

Example: if you have body at location 0,0 and sprite with origin 1,1 you should position that sprite on location -1,-1 in order for the two to rotate synchroniously!